# Table type of variable returning blank cells after update sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a select query returning two results and what I want is to save them in a table type of variable. This is how I am doing it:

```
declare @CompletedTotalValues table (CMedian int, CPerc int);
update @CompletedTotalValues set CMedian = t.CMed, CPercentile = t.CPerc
from(               
      Select CMed = dbo.median(case when cr.Priority = 1 then cr.Days else null end),
             CPerc = dbo.Percentile90(case when cr.Priority = 1 then cr.Days else null end)
      from  A a inner join B b on b.Id = a.Id
      where b.StatusId = 3
) t;
```

Here, when I run the subquery, I see CMed is 25 and CPerc is 43. However, when I execute `Select * from @CompletedTotalValues`, it is returning both column blank (no value it shows). Where is my mistake? Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: you have to INSERT before you can UPDATE...

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, when I add insert into @CompletedTotalValues values (0,0,0,0) before my update query it is working.

Comment: if your insert logic is correct, you shouldn't have to update... It should be the right values when you insert, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just insert the data in the first place?

```
DECLARE @CompletedTotalValues TABLE (CMedian INT, CPerc INT);
INSERT @CompletedTotalValues (CMedian, CPerc)
SELECT  CMed = dbo.median(CASE WHEN cr.Priority = 1 THEN cr.Days END),
        CPerc = dbo.Percentile90(CASE WHENn cr.Priority = 1 THEN cr.Days END)
FROM    A 
        INNER JOIN B ON b.Id = a.Id
WHERE   b.StatusId = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I go by the query you have shared, you are trying to update without even inserting any data in the table variable at first place. Is it?